Handling streamed audio in TIdHTTPServer
I can send an audio file from the TIdHTTPServer using OnCommandGet handler like that:
procedure THTTPServer.CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document = '/audiofile' then
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'audio/wav';
    AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create('c:\mono.wav', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  end;
end;

But how to properly organize the handler if the audio is streamed (not a file, just continuous PCM data) and should be fetched by chunks?

Related/dupe: Delphi video streaming Http Server the question was for video, but the same concept applies for audio
